# expected vs observed proportion for more than two categories

Tags: chi-squared-test, binomial-distribution

I show four colored cards to subjects asking them to choose one. Ideally all four colors should have equal probability of being chosen. But I notice that red is picked more frequently than others. Is there are test which can tell me if there is a real difference between expected and observed proportions?

Comment: Is "red" important, or are you just checking whether or not the four colours are equally probable? What led you to tag this "chi-squared"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you have data of sufficiently many subjects, you can test whether the difference between the observed and expected outcome is significant.

You calculate the probability $P$ of the specific outcome with only the constraints that are relevant to the problem assuming a hypothesis $H$, which is in this case: The probability of picking red is $\frac14$.

If this probability is smaller than some value $\alpha$ (which is usually taken to be approximately $0.01$), then hypothesis $H$ is rejected.

Example: If you had 100 subjects pick cards and 30 picked red and 70 did not pick red (it doesn't matter what colors this were, since the hypothesis is about red).

Then the probability that **at least** 30 picked red given the hypothesis that the probability of picking a red card is $\frac14$, can be calculated using the cumulative binomial distribution: $$P =1-\mathrm{binomcdf}(N,p,k)=1-\mathrm{binomcdf}(100,\tfrac14,30)\approx 0.1495$$

Since $0.1495>0.01$, we accept the hypothesis $H$. You can repeat this with your own numbers.